# Destructor that also deallocates memory for a particular Hash Class in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, hash, memory-leaks, destructor

I'm in the process of learning C++ and trying to write a Hash class. Everything works great so far, except for the fact that when my program finishes using the hash class, there's a memory leak associated with my hash table. I was hoping to get some help writing a destructor that would delete the elements that are stored in heap.

Here's my hashclass.h file:

```
class Hash {
public:
    Hash();
    /* Bunch of methods here*/
    virtual ~Hash();
private:
    static const int size = 20;

    struct item{
        string name;
        int number;
        item* next;
    };

    item* HashTable[size];

};
```

And in my hashclass.cpp I have the following implementation for my constructor:

```
Hash::Hash(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        HashTable[i] =  new item;
        HashTable[i]->name = "";
        HashTable[i]->number = 0;
        HashTable[i]->next = NULL; 
    }

}
```

Would anyone be able explain how to write the proper destructor that would deallocate all the memory blocks that are used to build this hash table.

Comment: The destructor aside, why are you priming each slot in your initial pointer array with a dynamic allocation. `nullptr` in that slot is more-than-adequate to indicate "nothing here" as a node-to-nowhere. And `item` is in need of its own parameterized constructor, as the only time you should find need to them is when you have data to store in the first place.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how I can use this information to build a destructor that would deallocate memory? I'm very novice when it comes to these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your source, the natural destructor would be:

```
Hash::~Hash()
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        while (HashTable[i])
        {
            item *victim = HashTable[i];
            HashTable[i] = victim->next;
            delete victim;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Your class is *not* [**Rule of Three**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) compliant. Read the linked article, as it is important, and the sooner you learn it the better.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig. You mentioned "...And item is in need of its own parameterized constructor, as the only time you should find need to them is when you have data to store in the first place."
I do store data in the item. It's just like a phone book. So the user inserts the data, and the key value pair is being stored in the hash table. Do I need to initialize the parameters in item structure?

Comment: What I mean by using a parameterized constructor is simply this: if you adopt the philosophy that your "table" is initially filled with `nullptr`, then the only time you ever need an `item` created is when you're actually inserting *real* data into you table of collision lists. Having a constructor that takes `(const std::string& s, int n, item *next = nullptr)` as the parameter list, and properly initializes the members of the structure with an [*initialization list*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html). Work with your `item`s long enough it will become more apparent why.

Comment: Great. I'll use your recommendation.

Comment: Having said that, should I also initialize the structure variables in 'item'? I still get some type of memory error in valgrind.

Comment: Then run down the valgrind report, find where the allocation is, and fix it. What I said about the Rule of Three noncompliance is true. Read that article, and debug where you seem to be failing to destroy whatever you're leaking.

Answer (score 0):

An approach for your destructor.

```
Hash::~Hash(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // first: you must delete HashTable[i]->next <-- your homework.
        // second: delete HashTable[i]
        if (HashTable[i])
            delete HashTable[i];
    }
}
```

As a general rule, you should always have the same amount of operator new and operator delete. If you have operator new[], you must use operator delete[].

For example, allocation:

```
char * foo = new char[size];
```

deallocation:

```
delete [] foo;
```